# Does JSSE support TLS RFCS 6520 heartbeat?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

TLS Heartbeat Extension (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520), which is available in OpenSSL. Does JSSE also support this extension ?

Comment: Adjusted your title and tags. JSSE consists of more than the `SSLEngine`. It contains two separate implementations, the `SSLEngine` and `SSLSocket`. They will both support the same things.

Comment: Thanks to @EJP . But I'm unable to find any heartbeat features in these 2 classes so far.

Comment: I don't think you will, but those aren't the actual classes to look at if you're talking about checking source code.